# PEAR Spreadsheet Excel Writer Autoload

Tags: php, excel, pear, spreadsheet, autoload

Hi I'm trying to fold the Excel spreadsheet writer functionality into an existing application. I'm using php 5.3 with namespaces and having a really difficult time getting the necessary classes to load.

I think the problem is that the file names are "Writer.php but the class methods are "Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer()". My autoloader is set up like this:

```
function __autoload($class) {
    $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);

    $splitArray = explode("_", $class);
    $class = $splitArray[(sizeof($splitArray) - 1)]; // piece1

    include($class . '.php');
}
```

Which loads the rest of my classes just fine but fails to load the spreadsheet ones. If I rename the files to match the method names it fails on trying to load the OLE classes. I don't really want to go though and rename all the classes in PEAR to get this working.

Anyone know a better way of going about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try PHPExcel instead--http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your `PEAR` path to your `include_path`, then

```
require_once "Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php"
```

You may also then want to explicitly require the OLE classes too.

Depending on your OS too the file names maybe case sensitive.

Comment: it still gives me an error:

`Fatal error: Class 'utilities\Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer' not found in utilities/Spreadsheet.php on line 23'`

I think because the auto loader is looking for a "Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer.php"

Comment: That is something that you need to handle in your autoloader then

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get the class to load, however, it lead to further issues. It seems that PEAR (or at least the version of PEAR on the shared host) is not compatible with php 5.3 namespaces.

So while I eventually got the class to load I was ultimately unable to load PEAR.

As a work around I ended up an writing XLS formatted XML doc and saving it out as a .xls file. It may not be a perfect solution but it works.

Thanks for the input though!